# Access IPMI / iLOM / iDRAC / any Java-based Remote Console applet via Proxy on OSX

Tags: ipmi, drac

This question is probably more of an OSX + Java / Proxy issue than a iLOM / DRAC / IPMI issue.

I am able to set up SSH tunnels for access to a server management network which contains various servers & network equipment (*Dell, SuperMicro, Sun, etc...*).  Using FoxyProxy + Firefox, I am able to access the web browser login pages for these server management interfaces (*iLOM / (i)DRAC, etc...*).

Most of these server management interfaces generally have a link to a Java `.jnlp` applet which is supposed to launch a remote management KVM console to the server, just as if you were hooking up a monitor & keyboard to it physically.  However, when I try to run the applet it just shows errors.

I have set up my [Java Proxy settings](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml) to use the same SSH tunnel that FoxyProxy is using.

#### SSH Tunnel:

```
ssh -f jcuzella@bastion-host.example.com -D 2500 -L 8080:10.123.231.123:8080 -N
```

#### Java Network / Proxy Settings:

[image: Java Network Proxy Settings]

#### FoxyProxy Settings:

[image: FoxyProxy settings]

#### Errors:

However, when I try to run the `Remote Console` applets through `FoxyProxy` + `Firefox`, I get errors similar to the following:

[image: Application Error: Unable to launch the application]
[image: More Information: Launch File (jnlp)]

The Java Exceptions look like these:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://10.123.213.123/Java/release/JViewer.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://some-server.ilom.example.com:80/iKVM__V1.69.21.0x0.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### How can I access the iLOM and launch a Remote Console Java applet through the proxy?

#### Java Version

I'm running `OS X 10.9.5 (13F1066)`.
I'm using Java version `1.7.0_75`, which is located here:

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Jul 21  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the proxy in java console:
https://darktraining.com/2011/05/12/Using-and-SSH-tunnel-and-socks-proxy-with-A-dell-DRAC-Dell-remote-access-controller/

Comment: Please add some of the information from the linked page into your answer in case the link ever dies.

Comment: I believe when I was having this problem that I did indeed follow the steps listed in that article.  I posted the "Java Network Proxy Settings" screenshot for what I tried.  I also remember trying `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`, either in Advanced -> socks proxy or just the main proxy box it seemed that both configurations did not result in the iDRAC / iLOM java applet working through the dynamic SSH port forward.  Luckily, this problem no longer plagues me anymore because I simply do not have to manage iDRAC or iLOM servers anymore ;-)